# Nothing showing up on Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For Some reason my data dosent show up when as you can see in main.html am putting the data in a table.. This is a meteor app, so dont worry about angular it is already installed using node, as i also have meteor on my computer.  I followed [this](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/dynamic-template) tutorial

main.html:

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="PartiesListCtrl">
   <table border = 1>
       <tr ng-repeat = "data in parties">
           <td>{{data.name}}</td>
           <td>{{data.description}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
</body>
```

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="socially">
<div ng-include src="'main.html'"></div>
</body>
```

app.js:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor']);

    angular.module('socially').controller('PartiesListCtrl',["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.parties = [
            {
                'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone',
                'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.'
            },
            {
                'name': 'All dubstep all the time',
                'description': 'Get it on!'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Savage lounging',
                'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.'
            }
        ];
    }]
   );
}
```

Comment: I think you overwrote your `<body>` tag in the `main.html` file? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No  im not.. In fact @TheLazyChap when im getting the body tag away im getting an error thats why i put it in..

Comment: add some static text on main.html see if it really got loaded onto the view.

Comment: Added a h1 tag and it worked.. @sdfacre

Comment: @sdfacre do you possibly have a team viewer so we can get the problem out quicker?

Comment: sorry, I don't have team viewer and I'm at work. Now, what did you see when you check the web source code of the table (browser developer tool -> inspect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be something like below.

```
angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor'])
.controller('PartiesListCtrl',["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.parties = [
            {
                'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone',
                'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.'
            },
            {
                'name': 'All dubstep all the time',
                'description': 'Get it on!'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Savage lounging',
                'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.'
            }
        ];
    }]
   );
```

**Changes**

Remove second instance of angular.module('socially') and directly use .controller or assign it to some variable and then use controller like below.

```
var socially = angular.module('socially', ['angular-meteor']);
socially.controller('PartiesListCtrl',["$scope", function ($scope) {
 //Your controller code goes here.
}]);
```

Do let me know if it doesn't work.

```js
angular.module('socially', [])
.controller('PartiesListCtrl',["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.parties = [
            {
                'name': 'Dubstep-Free Zone',
                'description': 'Can we please just for an evening not listen to dubstep.'
            },
            {
                'name': 'All dubstep all the time',
                'description': 'Get it on!'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Savage lounging',
                'description': 'Leisure suit required. And only fiercest manners.'
            }
        ];
    }]
   );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="socially">
<div ng-controller="PartiesListCtrl">
   <table border = 1>
       <tr ng-repeat = "data in parties">
           <td>{{data.name}}</td>
           <td>{{data.description}}</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
</body>
```